# how to write mysql statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I made a quiz game system (mysql+php).there are two tables:

question table:

```
qid            question        options      answer  level
23              1+1=?          1^2^3^4        2       1
24             10*10=?       1010^100^1000    100     1 
.....
3212          9999*32342/765   ...           ...      4 (more large the level is more difficult the question is)
```

### ...more that ten thousand records...

user table:

```
userID       username        used(this field store qid someone has answered that from question table )
1            mary           23,56 (means she had answered qid=23 qid=56 question from question table)
2            mike           1,4,6,2123,567,2341,678,431234,45125
3            jack           3,23,24,.....
...
```

### ..many users....

When a player logs in and starts to play the game, the system would select 4 questions from the `question` table that are `level=1` and 4 question that `level=2` ...4 question that `level=3` ....`level=4`.  All these question had not be used before according to the `used` from user table.

how to write the mysql statement?

Comment: That used column is going to get pretty big as more people play your game. I wonder whether that structure could be improved more

Comment: your 'used' field should be stored in another table.

Comment: Redesign your database scheme to use cross reference tables. Shoving answers/question id's into a single column will always lead to problems. Look at this link and just pretend that permissions is the questions that have been answered. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table

Comment: :), haha,,  thank you every much!

Answer (score 1):

With your current schema, you will need at least two queries. The first will return the `used` value to PHP. PHP will then need to use it in a second query:

```
$q   = mysql_query( 'select used from user_table where id=1' ) 
            or die( mysql_error() );
$row = mysql_result_array( $q );
$ids = $row[ 0 ];
$q   = mysql_query( 
    "SELECT * FROM (
       select * from question_table where level = 1 and qid not in ($ids) ORDER BY (RAND()) limit 4
    )
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM (
       select * from question_table where level = 2 and qid not in ($ids) ORDER BY (RAND()) limit 4
    )
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM (
       select * from question_table where level = 3 and qid not in ($ids) ORDER BY (RAND()) limit 4
    )
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM (
       select * from question_table where level = 4 and qid not in ($ids) ORDER BY (RAND()) limit 4
    )" 
) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: i was thinking about it and tested quite similar sql. ive got an error that i cant use `union` after `limit`

Comment: I just ran this on a wordpress database: `select ID from wp_posts where ID < 30 LIMIT 3 UNION select ID from wp_posts where ID < 50 LIMIT 10;` Worked like a charm.

Comment: If you leave LIMIT outside of a subquery, it will apply the LIMIT to the group and ignore all of the other LIMITs. If you put it in a subquery, then it only effects the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (and probably most efficient way) is to do it in 2 queries.

1. `SELECT used FROM user WHERE userID = 'mike'`
2. `SELECT * FROM question WHERE level = 1 qid NOT IN (result from query 1) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4`

Then repeat query 2 for each level.

Comment: but Sometimes I found,for example the result contains ...23,5,75,3,90... from query 1 , then there is '3' in the result from query 2.     Would mysql miss some qid when the set is large from query 1?

Comment: If the `used` field is large enough, there should you have problems. Be sure the result from query 1 isn't quoted.